# XGBoost original paper equation simplification

Tags: boosting

In the original XGboost paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02754), in section 3.3, the authors simplified equation 3:

[image]

To:

[image]

Shouldn't this be a positive sign with the target being -g/h? Wikipedia shows the same equation in the algorithm section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XGBoost but states target to be -g/h.

Comment: Arxiv papers sometimes have typos. Have you read the published paper?

Comment: yes the published one is the same (page 15): https://digital.lib.washington.edu/researchworks/handle/1773/44766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the original paper, I think you are correct.

Regarding Wikpedia: it seems that the term was originally $\left[-\frac{\hat{g}_m(x_i)}{\hat{h}_m(x_i)}-\phi(x_i) \right]^2$ but [someone edited it](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?diff=1164850953&oldid=1160929274&title=XGBoost) to $\left[\phi(x_i) - \frac{\hat{g}_m(x_i)}{\hat{h}_m(x_i)}\right]^2$. I think this change should be reverted.